# Getting the changed printer preferences for a printer from controlpanel through code

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have to print a document to any of the installed printers from the wpf application. User can select the printer and click on the print button. I am able to print the document with the selected printer. But if i change the printer preferences from the control panel **ex:** `Pages Per sheet`, `color` etc, I am not able to get those changed printer preferences for printing the document. I have used both the `printQueue`.`DefaultPrintTicket` and `printQueue.UserPrintTicket` in the code but both are giving the default settings only.

How can we always get the changed `printerpreferences` for a printer from control panel instead of default settings through the code and apply those printer preferences while printing?

Comment: Have you used the PrintDialog instance in your application?

Comment: Yes Iam using the PrintDialog instance in the application to call the print fuction with out showing the print dialog.

Comment: @bhanupriyat I'm having the same problem, did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the WPF printing classes, see:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ebf6d61-a356-41c3-a444-a24fb38416fe/printticket-not-reflecting-printing-preferences?forum=wpf

As a workaround you can use the `PrintDialog` (without showing it) to get the correct settings on the default printer, unfortunately you need to temporary change the windows default printer in order to get settings for other printers than the default one.

I wrote this method, seems to be working fine.

```
/// <summary>
///   Get current settings (encapsulated in an PrintTicket) for a specific printer.
/// </summary>
private static PrintTicket GetPrinterSettings(PrintQueue printer)
{
   try
   {
      // Note: Because of a bug in the WPF printing classes
      // this hack is unfortunately necessary in order to get the correct 
      // printer settings. The old/usual method often get the printer
      // standard settings instead of the custom settings. 
      // For more information see:
      // https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ebf6d61-a356-41c3-a444-a24fb38416fe/printticket-not-reflecting-printing-preferences?forum=wpf
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774420/getting-the-changed-printer-preferences-for-a-printer-from-controlpanel-through

      var printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
      string printerName = printer.FullName;
      string defaultPrinterName = printDialog.PrintQueue.FullName;

      PrintTicket ticket;
      if (defaultPrinterName != printerName)
      {
         // Temporary change default printer in order to get
         // correct printer settings on the specific printer.
         Win32.SetDefaultPrinter(printerName);
         printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
         ticket = printDialog.PrintTicket;
         Win32.SetDefaultPrinter(defaultPrinterName);
      }
      else
         ticket = printDialog.PrintTicket;
      return ticket.Clone();
   }
   catch
   {
      // If the method above fails, use the old method.
      return printer.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.Clone();
   }
}

public static class Win32
{
   [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no any particular instance in the PrintDialog to show case all the printerpreferences. But you can get every info with the corresponding properties in the corresponding instance. like `printDialog.PrintTicket.PagesPerSheet`  etc..